# Regex: how can exclude all TLD except my own domain

Tags: regex

I have an Asp.Net website on which I'm implementing some basic anti-spam stuff via the validation controls.

One such regex is: `"^(?!.*(//|[.]({com|net|info|uk|etc}))).*$"`

It pretty much does what it needs to as far as blocking goes — it doesn't need to be too sophisticated. However, I want to include the option to whitelist my own domain.

So, I want to block all .uk domains, except mydomain.co.uk.

This is a regex step beyond me — can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a nested [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) while `uk` to fail the already existing negative lookahead for `mydomain.co.` part before matching `uk`:

```sh
^(?!.*(//|[.](com|net|info|(?<!mydomain\.co\.)uk))).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pRSFpt/1)

Take note of `(?<!mydomain\.co\.)` which is a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to not to match `uk` if it is preceded by `mydomain.co.`.

Comment: That seem to work perfectly. Thanks for the quick response. Appreciated!